# Number of factors of $2^{p_1\cdots p_n}+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Let $p_1 <p_2 \cdots <p_n$ be the ordered prime numbers starting with $p_1=5$.

Let $a_n = 2^{p_1\cdots p_n}+1$.

It is elementary to show that $a_n$ has at least $4^n$ factors but this bound ($\tau(a_n)\geq 4^n$) does not seem to be sharp, hence my questions:

1. Do we know better bounds than $4^n$?
2. Could we estimate $\tau(a_n)$ when $n\to \infty$?

EDIT Nov 9, 2019
With the link I mentioned in comment I was able to show that $\tau(a_n)\geq 2^{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: The lower bound does not hold for $\tau(2^3+1)=3$.

Comment: That's right.  I changed $p_1$ to 5 (which still gives 4 divisors), otherwise $\tau (2^{3\cdot 5}+1) = 12$ and $\tau (2^{5\cdot 7}+1) = 2\cdot 4^2$.

Comment: We don't even have a sharp bound for the number of prime factors of $2^p-1$. Why should there be one for this more complicated expression?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, after some more research I found at the end of page 9 in https://imosuisse.ch/smo/skripte/imovorbereitung/rootsofunity/en-rootsofunity.pdf that we can get a much better bound. There isn't a lot of details though. Also, sometimes "more complicated" becomes "more general" and is easier to answer.

Comment: With the link I mentioned above, I was able to show that $\tau(a_n)\geq 2^{2^{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 6):

$\tau(2^{p_1\cdots p_n}+1) \ge 2^{2^n}$ is easy using [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem).
For every $d\big|p_1\cdots p_n$, except for $d=3$, there is a primitive prime divisor of $2^d+1$. Hence, $2^{p_1\cdots p_n}+1$ has at least $2^n$ distinct prime divisors.